# How to use form validation in vendor registration in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I have a default vendor registration form in that i want to use form validation on text field like Email and Gst in wordpress so how can do this ????

I have watched some youtube videos related to this problem but it shows some plugins and most of plugins are paid so can anyone solve this problem.